# F# Array.tryFindIndex start search from an index

Tags: f#

I wonder if there's a cheap(performance wise) option to search an index of array element which meets certain criteria starting from an index?

Array.tryFindIndex method doesn't have an argument startIndex. I could do Array.skip(n) and then search there but it seems expensive to create an array just for search. How do I do this?

I looked List also doesn't have that argument.
Do I have to use while ... do? Is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 6):

The base libraries try to provide functions for your convenience but they cannot possibly anticipate all use cases. Nothing wrong with writing your own if need be:

```
module Array =
    let tryFindIndexFrom i p (a : _ []) =
        let rec loop k =
            if k >= a.Length then None
            elif p a.[k] then Some k
            else loop (k + 1)
        if i < 0 then None else loop i
```

**EDIT:** `p` is the predicate testing the array elements. `tryFindIndexFrom` has the same signature as `tryFindIndex` but with the starting index added as first parameter.

**EDIT 2:** Added test for `k < 0` for fool-proof usage.

**EDIT 3:** Moved test for `k < 0` out of the loop as it needs to be checked only once.

Comment: Myabe explain that 'p' means predicate i.e. some function that returns true or false. Tthat's my guess .

Comment: @sashang: Indeed, ``p`` is the predicate testing the array elements. ``tryFindIndexFrom`` has the same signature as ``tryFindIndex`` but with the starting index added as first parameter.

Comment: If you add an `inline` after `let` the F# compiler can sometimes inline the predicate and thus avoid a virtual call. Also sometimes `ValueOption<_>` is useful to avoid GC pressure. Since OP talked about cheap performance-wise.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it using a lazy sequence of array indexes:

```
let input = [| 'a' .. 'z' |]

seq { 4 .. input.Length - 1 }
|> Seq.tryFind (fun i -> input |> Array.tryItem i = Some 'x')
```

I'll leave it to you to generalise this into a helper function if you think that's necessary.

The nice thing about the current form is that it's quite flexible. You can change the maximum index easily, or search backwards, e.g. `seq { input.Length - 1 .. -1 ..  4 }`.

Answer (score 2):

Follow your instinct. Considering `Array.skip` but noting the obvious waste of allocating a second array, you can take it one step further and generalize to the lazily evaluated `Seq.skip`, compose it with the standard `Seq.tryFindIndex` function and add the offset, if applicable.

```
let tryFindIndexMin n p =
    Seq.skip n
    >> Seq.tryFindIndex p
    >> Option.map ((+) n)
// val tryFindIndexMin : n:int -> p:('a -> bool) -> (seq<'a> -> int option)

[ for i in 0..3 ->
    [|"a"; "b"; "a"; "b"|]
    |> tryFindIndexMin i ((=) "a") ]
// val it : int option list = [Some 0; Some 2; Some 2; null]
```

Comment: This method doesn't have to allocate an intermediate array but it does still have to iterate through the `n` sequence items, which could be the slow part.